# How to change the position of star ratings for Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, rating-system

How can I reposition the star ratings on my archive and category pages? I would like to starts to be seen under the price, rather than in between the buy it now and price.

I've tried unhooking and floating left, but it doesn't seem to work. See my code below and [here](http://www.happyhealthymarket.com/) is a link to my site. Thank you!!

Functions.php:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 15 );
```

Style.css

```
.star-rating span
{
float: left;
}
```

Comment: use chrome to inspect it, and change the css with inspector to see changes

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.star-rating {
position: absolute!important;
margin-left: 25px!important;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: It looks like you added that css to `.star-rating span`.  It needs to be just `.star-rating`.

Comment: that seemed to mess up the star ratings for a single-product. Scroll down to the bottom of a single product page to see what I'm talking about. Two random star ratings are floating near the comment box.

Comment: Try changing `.star-rating` to `li .star-rating`